# How do I deserialize this JSON string back to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, interface

I am wanting to be able to use `JSON` to `serialize` and `deserialize` a `List<T>`, where the type is an `interface`.

I have the code working to `serialize` the `List<T>` to a string, but am not sure on how to `deserialize` the `JSON` string back into a `List<T>`.

Here is my code to `serialize` the `List<T>`:

```
List<IAndroidAsset1_1> androidAssets = new List<IAndroidAsset1_1>();

AndroidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1 androidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1 = new AndroidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1();
androidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1.Id = 1;
androidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1.icon = "TestIcon";
androidAssets.Add(androidMapMarkerIconAsset1_1);

AndroidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1 androidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1 = new AndroidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1();
androidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1.Id = 2;
androidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1.expiryDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
androidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1.webAddress = "http://www.test.com";
androidAssets.Add(androidMapMarkerSimpleImageAsset1_1);

string serializedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(androidAssets, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple
});
```

Here is the code that I have to `deserialize` the `JSON` string:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IAndroidAsset1_1>(serializedJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException'
>   occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'CanFindLocation.Interfaces.Android._1_1.IAndroidAsset1_1' because the
>   type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

Can I please have some help to `deserialize` the `JSON` string back to a `List<T>`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are serailizing a list not a single `IAndroidAsset1_1` object, so you need deserialize to `List<IAndroidAsset1_1>` type not `IAndroidAsset1_1`:

```
var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IAndroidAsset1_1>>(serializedJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
```